# ¿Como puedo hacer Post JSON en Postman agarrando como foreign key a un objeto que ya existe dentro de la base?

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, postman

Yo estoy utilizando springboot para crear un API utilizando el modelo First code, ya tengo varias clases creadas, sin embargo tengo una clase llamada "application.java"

```
@Entity
public class application {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = user.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_user",referencedColumnName = "username")
    private user user;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = tattoo.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_tattoo",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private tattoo tattoo;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = client.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_client",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private client client;
```

Al momento de insertar un objeto a ella por medio de Postman estoy creando los objetos "tattoo" y "client", pero el objeto user ya existe en la base de datos y debo referenciar el FK hacia ese objeto, de que manera debo hacer la consulta en Postman para que haga la referencia o como debo editar el código para que funcione.
Este es el Post en Postman:

```
{
     "userId":
     {
         "username" : "LaArepaConMiel"
     },
     "tattooId":
     {
         "style" : "Trival",
         "color" : "Black and white",
         "firstTattoo" : "True",
         "bodyShape" : "square",
         "bodyPart" : "shoulder",
         "size" : "10x10",
         "description" : "Moai trive design",
         "availability" : "Lunes",
         "budget" : "50000"
     },
     "client":
     {
         "firstName" : "Ajeno",
         "lastName" : "AjenoApellido",
         "email" : "AjenoEmail@gmail.com",
         "birthDate" : "1998-09-01",
         "phoneNumber" : "84221563"
     }
 }
```

Este es el Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/application")
public class applicationController {
@Autowired
applicationService applicationService;

@GetMapping()
public ArrayList<application> getApplications(){
    return applicationService.getApplications();
}

@PostMapping()
public application saveApplicationModel(@RequestBody application application){
    return this.applicationService.saveApplication(application);
}

@GetMapping( path = "/{id}")
public Optional<application> getApplicationByUsername(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    return this.applicationService.getById(id);
}
}
```

El repository

```
@Repository
     public interface applicationRepository extends CrudRepository<application, Integer> {   
}
```

Y el service

```
@Service
public class applicationService {
@Autowired
applicationRepository applicationRepository;

public
ArrayList<application> getApplications(){
    return (ArrayList<application>)applicationRepository.findAll();
}

public application saveApplication(application application){
    return applicationRepository.save(application);
}

public Optional<application> getById(Integer id){
    return applicationRepository.findById(id);
}
}
```

Gracias de antemano y estuve buscando en todo stackoverflow y no encontre, vi varios videos de springboot y los ejemplos que dan siempre son muy basicos.

Comment: tal vez quieras poner el codigo de tu modelo de datos